# how to use UI NIB instead of loadNibNamed for custom UI tableview cell in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a custom ui table view cell. I know i can use `loadNibNamed` method to use `.xib`
of the cell but that causes scrolling to be slow when my I have too much data in it .

I want to use UI nib because its lot faster than `loadNibNamed` method for loading custom cell `.xib` file .

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PostStreamCell";

PostStreamCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostStreamCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];    
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MemberCell" bundle:nil];  
    [cell.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MemberCell"];
}

cell.textlabel.text =@"xyzabc123";
```

I tried using code below in above "if "block but failed to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PostStreamCell" bundle:nil];      
[cell registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostStreamCell"];
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your xib file with a UITableViewCell as the top-level object. This is called Cell.xib
2. Create a UINib object based on this file
3. Register the UINib with the table view (typically in viewDidLoad of your table view controller subclass).

use the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, if you want one of the cells from the nib, you dequeue it:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

This either creates a new instance from the nib, or dequeues an existing cell.

Comment: so should i remove if(cell == nil ) check in cellforrowatindexpath method?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to register the Xib once, so this regiserNib code should go within the viewDidLoad method of your class file

```
 UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PostStreamCell" bundle:nil];

 [self.tablview registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PostStreamCell"];
```

Then within your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method of your tableview

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PostStreamCell";

    PostStreamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textlabel.text =@"xyzabc123";
}
```

This will work for you as you need it.

Cheers

**Edit in response to PostStreamCell error***

Please make sure your custom UITableViewCell xib has the 'PostStreamCell' identifier, which you can set in this part of the IB

[image]

Please note the xib is a UITableViewCell object.

**Update - pic showing where to check custom class files associated with xib**

Within the Utilities of the IB, please make sure your custom UITableViewCell uses your custom class files PostStreamCell. Please check they're shown in this part of the IB.

Also within your UIViewController class files, (where you have the UITableView methods etc) make sure to

```
#import "PostStreamCell.h"
```

[image]

Comment: so should i remove if(cell == nil ) check in cellforrowatindexpath method?

Comment: @warzone_fz It will work fine without it. if(cell==nil) can be used to handle when there's no reusable cells to dequeue so in there you would create one, though as said, it'll work fine if it's not there too.

Comment: at this line    PostStreamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Have you imported the PostStreamCell custom tablviewCell class file?

Comment: this exception is coming : cell reuse indentifier in nib (HorizontalCell) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (PostStreamCell)

Comment: I'll update the answer as need to direct you to a screen shot.

Comment: actually i used this instead because  when i used ur code then it was giving error that registerNib method does'nt exists: [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Comment: hey jim , i added identifier in .xib but still crashes at same line with same error

Comment: @warzone_fz I've updated the answer once more. It sounds like your custom cell isn't using your custom class files PostStreamCell. The edited answer shows a pic of where to look in the IB and this is where you'd add the ref to the class files. The code itself will work, providing your other aspects of the table is set up correctly.